# Complex limit proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Definition: Say $f: S \longleftrightarrow \mathbb{C} \longleftrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $z_0 \in S$, $l \in \mathbb{C}$. We say $$\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = l_0$$ if $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $0<|f(z) - l|< \varepsilon$, $\forall z \in B(z_0, \delta)$.

Need to prove $z^2+1$ tends to 0 as $z$ tends to $i$.

For $z \in B(i,\delta )$, this means $|z-i|<\delta \iff -\delta +2i<z+i< \delta +2i$:

$$|z^2 +1| = |z+i||z-i| < \delta |\delta +2i | = \delta^2 + 2\delta i <^* \delta +2\delta i = \delta (1+2i) < ^{**} (\varepsilon / (1+2i))(1+2i) = \varepsilon$$

$\delta < 1$ for *

$\delta <\varepsilon / (1+2i)$ for **

Choose $\delta < \min \{ 1, \varepsilon / (1+2i) \}$

Was I allowed to make delta in terms of a complex number which was $1+2i$? Also is my proof correct?

Comment: There is no ordering on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @detnvvp i don't get what you mean by that

Comment: You cannot break the absolute value. $|z-i|<\delta$ denotes distance in $\mathbb C$, not, absolute value in $\mathbb R$. Also, $\delta$ has to be a positive number.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $\delta^2+2\delta i<\delta+2\delta i$ because there is no inequality for complex numbers.  Instead, you should use the triangle inequality to write $|\delta\cdot(\delta+2i)|\leq|\delta|^2+2|\delta|$ and then use the real numbers.